# Ошибка при запуске gulp c консоли : gulp img

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Собственно создал новый проект с gulp. 
Node -v

```
v12.8.1
```

npm -v

```
6.10.2
```

gulp -v

```
[11:22:39] CLI version 3.9.1
[11:22:39] Local version 4.0.2
```

Сам gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

function img() {
    console.log(2);
}

gulp.task('img', img);
```

Собственно при вводе комманды gulp img , в консоли я так понимаю должна вывестись "2"! Но при этом получаю ошибку типа :

```
MacBook-Pro-Rostislav:gulp_lavrik rostislavdonec$ gulp css
[11:30:27] Using gulpfile ~/gulp/gulp_lavrik/gulpfile.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129
    gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
MacBook-Pro-Rostislav:gulp_lavrik rostislavdonec$
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

откатил gulp до 3-й версии:
npm install gulp@3.9.1

Удалил папку node_modules

далее
npm i 
... и все заработало! )